# Random equation-does it make sense?

Tags: probability-theory, random

What is the probability that the equation $$x^2+2bx+c=0$$ has real roots?
Answer is exactly $1$. (or $100$%)

For example: if $b=1$ and $c=2$ roots are complex.

Does it make sense?

If $P(A)=0$, then  $A$ is an event which cannot happen, and If $P(A)=1$   then $A$ is an event which  $\textbf{inevitably }$ occur. (Is this definition correct?)

what does it mean that probability equals $1$ (or $100$%)?

Comment: Looking at $(b,c)$ as random vector in e.g. $\mathbb R^2$ it can be that they are distributed is such a way that $P(b^2-c\geq0)=1$. If a context like that lacks then it makes no sense.

Comment: You ask a specific question about second order equations roots, and then a very general one about probability and the meaning of probability $1$. You should clarify your problems.

Comment: Evens with probability zero are not impossible to occur, and events with probability one are not guaranteed to occur. If you pick a random integer, the probability that is 7 equals zero, but it is possible to pick 7.

Probabilities over infinite possibilities are formalized by measure theory; a set with measure zero doesn't have to be non-empty, so an event with probability zero doesn't have to be impossible.

Comment: The correct terminology is almost surely (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense, as pointed out by @drhab.  But you could interpret the problem as follows:

> let $p(R)$ be the probability that $x^2+2bx+c$ has real roots when $b$ and $c$ are chosen randomly and independently from a uniform distribution on $[-R,R]$; then find $\lim_{R\to\infty}p(R)$.

In this case we have
$$p(R)=P(c\le b^2)=1-\frac1{4R^2}\int_{-\sqrt R}^{\sqrt R} R-b^2\,db
  =1-\frac1{3\sqrt R}$$
provided $R\ge1$, and
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}p(R)=1\ .$$

Comment: (+1) Nice solution. A tiny point: should $\frac{1}{R^2}$ be $\frac{1}{4R^2}$ because interval length is $2R$?

Comment: @MickA Fixed, thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 0):

Probability 1 doesn't been that it is inevitably. For example, the probability of throwing a dart not on a diagonal of a specific square is 1. However, it is not impossible that the dart lands exactly on the diagonal.